# Error while submitting word count topology in Apache storm

Tags: java, apache-storm

This is the basic wordcount topology I tried to run. But I am recieving error as 'INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.SessionTrackerImpl - SessionTrackerImpl exited loop!'. Can anyone help me with this??

When i removed cluster.shutdown(), tweets are coming continously until I press cntrl+c. Again wordcount is not showing ##

```
     import java.util.Arrays;
     import backtype.storm.Config;
     import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
     import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
     import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
     public class TwitterHashtagStorm {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String consumerKey = "************";
    String consumerSecret = "***************";
    String accessToken = "**********";
    String accessTokenSecret = "***********";
    String[] keyWords = {"apple"};
    Config config = new Config();
    config.setDebug(true);
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("twitter-spout", new TwitterSampleSpout(consumerKey,
            consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, keyWords));
    builder.setBolt("twitter-hashtag-reader-bolt", new HashtagReaderBolt())
            .shuffleGrouping("twitter-spout");
    builder.setBolt("twitter-hashtag-counter-bolt",
            new HashtagCounterBolt()).fieldsGrouping(
            "twitter-hashtag-reader-bolt", new Fields("hashtag"));
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("TwitterHashtagStorm", config,
            builder.createTopology());
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    cluster.shutdown();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

10 seconds (10000 ms) is probably not be enough time for the Twitter connection to establish and for tweets to come into your topology. You should set the sleep call to something longer (several minuets at a minimum).

As for showing the work count, does your HashTagCounter bolt print out the counts to stout? If so the print out may be lost in the log messages from Storm. Try setting `config.setDebud(false)` (to cut down the log messages and give you a chance of seeing the count) or rewrite HashTagCounter to emit the messages to another location (a message broker, local socket reciever etc) separate from the console you are running Storm from.